# using IndexOf in Mid function

Tags: vb.net, string

Perhaps this is a simple solution for most, but I can't get this to work like it should according to syntax.

I have this line of text "Part Number123456Price$50.00"

I want to pull the part number out of it, so I use this function...

```
str = Mid(str, str.IndexOf("Part Number") + 12, str.IndexOf("Price"))
```

My results are str = "123456Price$50.0" every time. I know the part number can vary in length so I need a solid solution of pulling this out.

Comment: second argument to Mid() is the number of characters, isn't it?  so you need to figure the length of the numeric string and not the offset to Price.

Comment: So something like i = str.IndexOf("PartNumber") + 12;  str = Mid(str, i, str.IndexOf("Price") - i);

Comment: If you want a short one-liner, then `str.Split({"P"c, "r"c})(3)` will return `123456`

Answer (score 3):

It can be confusing to mix the legacy VB string methods (such as Mid) with the .Net string methods (like IndexOf). The VB methods use 1 as the index of the first character while the .Net methods use 0.

The following code will extract the part number from a string

```
Dim str As String = "Part Number123456Price$50.00"
Dim iPart As Integer = str.IndexOf("Part Number") + 11
Dim iPrice As Integer = str.IndexOf("Price")
str = str.Substring(iPart, iPrice - iPart).Trim
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Mid()` function of Visual Basic is documented as having three arguments: (1) a string, (2) the beginning location in the string, and (3) the number of characters to copy.

So if your string is "Part Number123456Price$50.00" and you want to pull the part number as a series of digits, the "123456" part of the string, using the `Mid()` function then you need to find the beginning of the part number digit string and to then know the number of digits.

If your string is in the variable `str` then you can find the offset by something like `str.IndexOf("Number") + len("Number")` which will provide the offset to after the string "Number".

Next you need to find the number of digits so you would do something like `str.IndexOf("Price")` to find where the text "Price" begins and then subtract from that offset the offset of where the digits begin.

The result of all of this is you need a bit of code something like the following.  I have not tested this source as I am not a VB programmer so it may need a tweak and you might want to put some checks on data validity as well.

```
Dim TextNumber as String = "Number"
Dim TextPrice as String = "Price"

iOffset = str.IndexOf(TextNumber) + len(TextNumber)
str = Mid(str, iOffset, str.IndexOf(TextPrice) - iOffset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if Price is always the format $00.00, this will also work.

`Dim str as String = "Part Number123456Price$50.00"`
`str = str.Remove(str.IndexOf("Price"))`